# Why Pancakeswap declared the whole contract of SyrupBar in the MasterChef contract

Tags: solidity, abstract

Panacakeswap declared the whole of the syrupbar and cake token contracts code (methods and implementation, not even abstract contract) along side the Masterchef's contract code just to declare them as variable type just like you would do with interface

```
// The CAKE TOKEN!
CakeToken public cake;
// The SYRUP TOKEN!
SyrupBar public syrup;
```

Isn't this what `Interface` exists for ? I can't wrap my head around why they would , so i thought maybe someone on here might know . hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference if you use an interface or a contract for variables since the compiler only uses the function signature to create the function call it doesn't use the implementation at all.

If you use the contract the compiler will take slightly longer to compile since it has to validate the contract.

One problem with interfaces is that when modifying a function signature you have to make changes in two places, the contract and the interface.